# Send message directly to Subscription

Tags: azure, servicebus, azureservicebus

Is it possible to send a message directly to a Subscription queue?

Scenario:

A message failed, dropped onto the deadletter, the message has been picked up manually using defer, cloned and needs to be sent to the queue it was first deadlettered on, but NOT the topic.

Can I send a message directly to a subscriber?

I've considered creating a separate retry queue per subscriber, where the handling service will also receive messages from but i'd rather not do this.

Comment: I need this functionality as well and have submitted a suggestion to Microsoft: http://feedback.azure.com/forums/216926-service-bus/suggestions/9295470-resubmit-dead-letter-message-back-to-the-subscript

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this is a similar question to the one you asked earlier: [Azure Service Bus Subscriber Deadletter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22056149/azure-service-bus-subscriber-deadletter)

this is not possible, as far as I know.  the only thing you could do is to add an extra filter on every subscription that has something like SubscriptionName='SubscriptionA'.  If you then want to send you deadlettered message to the specific subscription, you can add a property SubscriptionName to it, to achieve your goal.  Take into account that you also have to make sure that in your original filter, you add a condition to indicate that the property SubscriptionName should not exist.

I agree however, that it would be a nice scenario to 'undeadletter' a message, so that it ends up again in his original subscription.

Comment: That's a really nice solution. Thanks man! It wouldn't have occurred to me to use a filter to achieve this!

Comment: I ended up with LINQPad snippet that temporary modifies all topic subscriptions' (except target one) rules adding condition to filter out messages annotated by generated "resubmission-tag" property. Then program receives DLQ, annotates messages with "resubmission-tag" and puts them back into topic. This way all but target subscription will effectively drop the messages as not matching to any rule.

Comment: Adding a 'recovery' subscription with SubscriptionName='SubscriptionA' filter consumed also by the original service would do it, no need to alter other subscription filters