# Azure service bus - dead lettering

Tags: c#, azure, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

Is there a way for me to send a message directly into a Azure service bus deadletter queue for a subscription without doing this operation on the parent subscription?

Here is a bit more detail about the problem :

We have a Azure function that has a service bus trigger on it, once a message is received, it hands the message over to a durable function orchestrator and completes the original message.

The problem we are trying to solve is how do we move the message into the deadletter queue for the subscription if the durable function orchestrator fails (after retries have exhausted).

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more details about the Topic and Subscription settings in your Service Bus Namespace where you want this behavior.

Comment: What is this operation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Service Bus Subscriber Deadletter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22056149/azure-service-bus-subscriber-deadletter)

Comment: Also related: [Send message directly to Subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22097231/2363967)

Comment: You can't send messages directly to a subscription, but you can add filters to your subscriptions so when you send messages to a topic only one subscription receives the message. You would also need to add a flag to the message content or headers, and update the subscriber to deadletter the message instead of processing it normally when it sees the flag. This may not be the best solution to your problem. What are you trying to solve?

Comment: hey Andrew, We are using durable functions in our processing pipeline, the client function uses a SB trigger, that completes the message once it has successfully handed over the message to the durable function. The problem we are trying to solve is how to put the message back to the deadletter queue ones the orchestrator fails (after retry has exhausted)

Comment: After number of retries(as per retry config count), messages will automatically moved to dead letter queue.